# Declare a service(to be private) in android

Tags: android, service, android-manifest

- How would it be possible to create a private service? I mean my
  custom service should not be accessible by other applications? What
  parameters I should define in `AndroidManifest.xml` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply do not include an `<intent-filter>`. Then your service will only be accessible by components within your application. You would use an explicit `Intent` to interact with it (e.g., `new Intent(this, MyPrivateService.class)`).

Comment: @AownRaza: Other than to not have an `<intent-filter>` in the manifest file for the service, no, nothing else is required. Having no `<intent-filter>` automatically sets `android:exported="false"`, which is what blocks third-party apps from accessing your service. While you could have an `<intent-filter>` *and* set `android:exported="false"`, there is no good reason to do so.

Answer (score 3):

As commonsware told that is a great answer.Also you can do in menifest also like this :

```
android:exported="false"
```

Comment: Having no <intent-filter> is better solution, rather than setting this attribute in manifest.

Comment: @AownRaza ok and why that is ? can u explain if u have time ?

Comment: Just learned :p , Not having <intent-filter> automatically sets android:exported to 'false'.

Comment: @AownRaza then u can't say it's a bad idea, it depends on the requirement.If you want an intent-filter, you have to go with my option else commonsware is right.Accept his answer first of all.

Comment: From the doc, "You can ensure that your service is available to only your app by including the android:exported attribute and setting it to false. This effectively stops other apps from starting your service, even when using an explicit intent." https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#Declaring